# Html a element target _blank not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript constant:

```
const url = 'www.google.com';
```

And I am trying to open it in a new window everytime someone selects the following link:

```
<a href={url} target="_blank">Google</a>
```

but instead I get:

```
localhost:8080/firstApp/index.html#https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/b5y4hrpg/  The target URL (which is a 404, of course) opens in a new tab as expected.  Do you have an example which demonstrates the problem?  Can you elaborate on what the problem *is* exactly?

Comment: "not working" is not a clear problem statement. What happens that is different to what you expect to happen? Is the generated DOM the DOM you expect? It *looks* like you just made a typo and forgot the scheme on the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "//" to your url like this:

```
const url = "//www.google.com";
```

Comment: Careful though with this solution. If you run a https website, and you want to go to another site which is http, this will link to the https version of that site. `//` is a sortof shortcut for 'the protocol I'm using myself'

Answer (score 1):

Your url should start with `http` or `https`